# What is the font used in this logo?

Tags: fonts, logo, font-identification

What is the font used on this logo or any similar to it?

[image]

Comment: **To find a font from a picture:** http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Comment: mtopia & Lollero: [WhatTheFont Results](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/results?ch%5B0%5D=T&ch%5B1%5D=H&ch%5B2%5D=E&ch%5B3%5D=S&ch%5B4%5D=T&ch%5B5%5D=&ch%5B6%5D=L&ch%5B7%5D=E&wtfserver=aws_wtf2&id=001c8aaa4e0a20b6000eeba900005af0&glyphcount=8&imageid=0&x=107&y=46)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

its possibly [Futura Cond Medium](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/urw/futura/t-medium-condensed/) and drop shadow effect applied.and this is similar to given font also..

Comment: Probably, but it's been customised. The terminals on the S have been rounded off, and the crossbar of the H dropped to align with the middle arm of the E.

Comment: i know but  its similar to given font

Comment: The S is a totally different shape too, plus the T is wider and the crossbar of both H and E are different.  Given the different shape of S alone I'd say it is not based on this font, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Lollero gave you a good answer. Joshmax image has expired.
From myfonts.com, the result is

[image]

Comment: and none of those match